# extract lines that their columns contains only a certain pattern

Tags: regex, file, unix, awk, grep

I have a file that contains some lines
that lines look like this :

```html
zadde205554800156569001
sfsdf848532300258112668
fsdfs552258800556220056
.
.
.
dzaed686745800158748048
```

I am looking to get only lines that contain `001` and `005` starting from the column 13 using some awk and regex

so the output should be like that :

```html
zadde205554800156569001
fsdfs552258800556220056     
dzaed686745800158748048
```

I have tried some grep command but in vain

Comment: What’s the regex you tried? Haven’t tested it, but it could be similar to this: `/.{12}(?=.*00(?:1|5)).+/` with the option that `.` doesn’t match line breaks.

Answer (score 1):

## Description

```
^.{12}(?:001|005)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

This regular expression will do the following:

- allows the string to start with any 12 characters
- requires the string to have substrings `001` or `005` at the 13th character

## Example

**Live Demo**

https://regex101.com/r/lQ2oD6/1

**Sample text**

```
zadde205554800156569001
sfsdf848532300258112668
fsdfs552258800556220056
.
.
.
dzaed686745800158748048
```

**Sample Matches**

```
zadde205554800156569001
fsdfs552258800556220056
dzaed686745800158748048
```

## Explanation

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of a "line"
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  .{12}                    any character except \n (12 times)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    001                      '001'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    005                      '005'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: But `001` or `005` shouldn’t necessarily start _at_ the 13th character but _from_ the 13th character.

Comment: @Xufox, that wasn't obvious in the question - but you can easily use `.{12,}` to match any twelve or more characters.  Or simply remove the line-start match instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '/.{12}00[15]/' file
zadde205554800156569001
fsdfs552258800556220056
dzaed686745800158748048

$ grep -E '.{12}00[15]' file
zadde205554800156569001
fsdfs552258800556220056
dzaed686745800158748048

$ sed -E -n '/.{12}00[15]/p' file
zadde205554800156569001
fsdfs552258800556220056
dzaed686745800158748048
```

Comment: Although this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Comment: No it wouldn't. That'd be like commenting `i++` with `increment i`. There are benefits to be gained in looking up a man page if you don't understand the basics.

Comment: More like commenting `i++` with *post-increment i, because we promised we'd return the old value here*, if explained appropriately.  That's IMO, and I think your opinion differs, so I'll leave it at that.